# Additional parameters of GUILayout.Label

Tags: user-interface, unity-game-engine

The Unity manual does not give examples of the `params` in the following particular version of `GUILayout.Label` (or is it somewhere else that I cannot seem to find?)

```
public static void Label(Texture image, GUIStyle style, params GUILayoutOption[] options);
```

So, I am wondering how to change the **font size** of the following code that I am dealing with:

I have a normal `OnGUI()` in an **Editor** file:

```
GUILayout.BeginHorizontal( displayStyle1 );
GUILayout.Label( "Has title?" );

if ( hasTitle )
{
    if( GUILayout.Button( "yes", GUILayout.Width(40) ) )
    {
        hasTitle = true;
    }

    GUILayout.EndHorizontal();              
}
```

and I have my own `MyOnGUI()` in an **Executor** file:

```
if( fieldInput.HasTitle )
{
    GUILayout.BeginHorizontal( displayStyle1 );
    GUILayout.Label( fieldInput.Title, displayStyle1 );
    GUILayout.EndHorizontal();
}
```

Once you press *yes* and enter the *title* in the Editor, what you get after the Executor runs needs to be in bigger font, so I thought I should modify this line:

```
GUILayout.Label( fieldInput.Title, displayStyle1 );
```

therefore, I need to see an example of how to specify a bigger font as 3rd parameter...

Is this possible? Is it the right way of directly changing font size without modifying the set styles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var style= GUI.skin.GetStyle("label");
style.fontSize = 24; // whatever you set
GUILayout.Label( fieldInput.Title, style);
```

Comment: Thank you David!  It solved my problem.  An observation:  It seems to _stay in effect_ unless changed again explicitly in code.  I mean even when I remove the code, the font size stays the same, as if a system settings has been changed permanently.  Do you know which system script deals with the _skin_ settings, and where the _default_ and _label_ styles reside?

Comment: before you call style.fontsize=24, cache the default fontsize: var defaultSize = style.fontSize; and you can revert it back  using defaultSize after your big font label is drawn.